# Netbeans Executable Linux C

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, executable, valgrind

I am currently building a program in C in netbeans at Ubuntu (Linux OS) and I want to parse it to valgrind for memory leaks. So I want to locate the executable that Netbeans create and run it throught terminal with valgrind. So far I cannot locate where Netbeans saves the executable so I am stuck. I know that I can compile the program from terminal but I have a lot of files in different folders so it would be convinient if I could just take the executable from Netbeans.

Alternatively is any way to connect the Netbeans IDE with valgrind?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Build your program on a command line, e.g. using [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108)). You don't need any IDE, just use a good editor like [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch my problem is that in my project I have about 40 files in different folders. So making a makefile or compiling it throught terminal would require a lot of time and would be painful.

Comment: No, writing a makefile for a small 40 files project is easy. I added a link to some example. You can adapt it to suit your needs. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8025816/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok I will go this way since it doesn't exist any better solution, but how do you set the path for  a .c file from a different folder?

Comment: You just type the file path (you can set some `Makefile` variable, e.g. `SOURCELIST=` to a list of files) Notice that Linux don't have folders (it is a desktop illusion), only directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it. For everyone looking where the executable is located go to:

```
NetBeansProjects->ProjectName->dist->Debug->GNU LINUX(x86)
```

and there, is located the output when you click debug tool on Netbeans. For convinience right click on it and then make link and drag the link wherever you like/