# How to compile and run a program that uses multiple files through terminal?

Tags: c++, terminal

So I'm trying to practice and learn how to use a text editor and the command line interface (terminal on mac) but i'm having trouble getting it to compile. I'm writing in c++ and i've separated my main file, class and class definitions into multiple files. I want to compile and run the program using terminal but am having issues. I use

```
 g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.h -o run
```

to compile and I get the error message "cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files."

I'm planning on having even more files in this program and don't know if this is even the best way to compile each time? Regardless, how do I compile this program so that I can run? I know the program doesn't have any errors because I tested it in the IDE Xcode.

Comment: Remove the header from the compile line, you don't need to compile headers.

Comment: BTW, a program can (and usually do) have errors even if it is compiled without diagnostics from the compilers. These errors are called *bugs* and you might spend weeks to find and correct one!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you could type several commands (`-std=c++11` tells the compiler that it is [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) code, `-Wall` asks for almost all warnings, `-Wextra` asks for more of them, `-g` asks for debug information, and `-c` avoids a linking step)

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -c file1.cpp
 g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -c file2.cpp
 g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -c file3.cpp
```

These commands are generating object files `file1.o`, `file2.o`, `file3.o` which you can link to make an executable:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -g file1.o file2.o file3.o -o run
```

BTW, you could have run all in a single command:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp -o run
```

but this is not optimal (since usually you edit one file at once, and the other files might not need to be recompiled).

But you really want to **use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)**, by writing your `Makefile` (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108)) and simply compiling with `make`; if you change only `file2.cpp` then `make` would notice that only `file2.o` has to be regenerated (and the final link to make again `run`)

You don't need to compile header files (they are preprocessed by the `g++` compiler). You might be interested in [precompiled headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) and makefile dependencies [generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025816/841108).

Once your program is debugged (with the help of a debugger like `gdb` and also of [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)....) you could ask the compiler to do [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) by replacing `-g` with `-O` or `-O2` (you could even compile with both `-g -O`). If you benchmark your program (e.g. with `time`)  don't forget to ask the compiler to optimize!

PS. Your `g++` commands might need [more arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC), e.g. `-I`... to add an include directory, `-DNAME` to define a preprocessor name, `-L`... to add a library directory, `-l`... to link a library, and *order of arguments is important for `g++`*