# In Makefiles GCC C programs, What are .d files and also what is a wildcard.?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

In Makefiles GCC C programs, What are .d files and also what is a wildcard.?

Rgds,

Comment: [Wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character), [dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394609/makefile-header-dependencies)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These `*.d` files usually (and just conventionally) are `make` dependencies (but perhaps, and unlikely, [D-language](http://dlang.org/) source code).

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler knows about `-M` (and related) [preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), which asks `make` to ....

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.

With the help of a few good `Makefile` tricks, you could write a  `Makefile` automatically dealing with dependencies, e.g. with things like

```
 ## dependencies of foo.c
 foo.d: foo.c
      $(COMPILE.c) -M $^ -o $@
 ## include them
 -include foo.d
```

About `$(wildcard *.c)`, read the [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), section on [file name functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html). So `$(wildcard *.c)` is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) the `*.c` by `make` expanding it into the list of files ending with `.c`; you could use it e.g. to define a `make` variable: `SOURCE_FILES= $(wildcard *.c)`, etc.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025816/841108), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) examples.

Don't forget to try `make -p` to understand all the good builtin rules known by GNU `make`.... Use `make --trace` or [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)`-x` for debugging your `Makefile`-s.