# GNU make does not build headers correctly if changed

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

I have this makefile:

```
CC=g++

CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all: hello

hello: main.o client.o
        $(CC) main.o client.o -o hello

client.o: client.cpp client.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) client.cpp -o client.o

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o

clean:
        rm -rf *o hello
```

Whenever I make changes in hello.h, client.o is rebuilt when I execute make. But when I try the resulting executable ./hello the change does not seem to happen.

The change is only reflected on ./hello if I add client.h to the main.o: rule like that

```
main.o: main.cpp client.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o
```

This will make things very difficult to maintain my code, any idea how to solve this problem?

Edit:
tried this change:

```
main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MD main.cpp -o main.o
```

but did not help.

UPDATE (final version):

```
TARGET = hello

CC = g++

CPPFLAGS = -Wall -MP -MD

LINKER = g++ -o
LFLAGS = -Wall

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.d)

RM = rm -rf

DIR_GUARD = mkdir -p $(@D)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        @$(DIR_GUARD)
        @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
        @$(DIR_GUARD)
        @$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
        @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

-include $(DEPS)

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
        @$(RM) $(OBJDIR)/* $(BINDIR)/*
        @echo "Cleanup complete!"
```

Thanks guys for all the help, you are truly amazing.

Comment: You want to use `gcc`'s `-Mx` option family and generate a list of header dependencies to include into your makefile.

Comment: i tried -MP but it does not work and also -MD, i added them to the CFLAGS, is this what you meant?

Comment: Show what you've tried in your makefile exactly. Remove the C++ code, it's not relevant for the problem. We can believe you, you have included the header files correctly.

Comment: i tried:
`main.o: main.cpp; 
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MD main.cpp -o main.o`

Comment: Add such information to your question please. Also how did you include the results to your makefile?

Comment: ok added to the question. what do you mean by include the results to your makefile?

Comment: There's a `.d` file generated using that option, that's supposed to be included in your makefile.

Comment: (Y) found it, and trying to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dependency of `main.o` on `client.h` is not specified in your `Makefile`. Use:

```
main.o: main.cpp client.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o
```

Comment: this will make my code very hard to maintain, as adding any new class will require that, is there another way of specifying that without changing the main.o ?

Comment: @Ghooo, If you are using gcc/g++, lookup the options `-MMD` and `-MD`.

Comment: Also see [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html).

Comment: the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation) was really helpful.