# Object file target not matching implicit rule with pattern

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU makefiles to build a C project. I want to keep all build artifacts on an isolated build tree in order to minimize clutter. The project looks like this:

```
$prefix/
    include/$tree/program.h
    source/$tree/program.c
    build/
        objects/$tree/program.o
        dependencies/$tree/program.d
```

Where `$prefix` represents the directory of the project and `$tree` represents an arbitrary folder structure.

I wanted to match source files in the `source/` directory to their object and dependency file counterparts in the `build/` tree. So, I wrote the following rules:

```
# Remove the built-in rules
%.o : %.c

$(objects_directory)/%.o : $(source_directory)/%.c $(dependencies_directory)/%.d
    $(compiler_command_line) $(compiler_option_output) $@ $<

$(build_directory)/$(target) : $(objects)
    $(compiler_command_line) $(compiler_option_output) $@ $^
```

Make correctly figures out the compilation `target` and the object files needed to build it. However, make stops at this point with the error:

> No rule to make target `'build/objects/project/program.o'`, needed by `'build/program.dll'`.

**So why is this happening, and how do I fix it?**

I investigated the problem by running `make --print-data-base`, the output of which included:

```
# Not a target:
build/objects/project/program.o:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  File does not exist.
#  File has not been updated.
```

Which suggests that the prerequisite is not matching the implicit rule as intended. However, I verified that it does match when I tried to work my way backwards by writing:

```
object := build/objects/project/program.o
$(object:$(objects_directory)/%.o=$(source_directory)/%.c)
$(object:$(objects_directory)/%.o=%)
```

These lines result in `source/project/program.c` and `project/program`, which means the *stem* is being correctly computed.

I have studied the GNU make documentation and I don't remember reading anything that suggests that this kind of pattern matching can't happen in implicit rule definitions.

---

Here are the variable definitions:

```
include_directory := include
source_directory := source

build_directory := build
objects_directory := $(build_directory)/objects
dependencies_directory := $(build_directory)/dependencies

sources := $(wildcard $(source_directory)/**/*.c)
objects := $(sources:$(source_directory)/%.c=$(objects_directory)/%.o)

# Take the name of the project's directory
target := $(notdir $(CURDIR)).dll

compiler_dependency_file = $(patsubst $(source_directory)/%.c,$(dependencies_directory)/%.d,$<)
compiler_options = -I $(include_directory) -MMD -MF $(compiler_dependency_file)

CC = gcc
compiler_command_line = $(CC) $(compiler_options) $(CFLAGS)
compiler_option_output = -o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't the pattern matching. The root of the problem was in the dependency prerequisite of the implicit rule.

The dependency file isn't supposed to be a prerequisite in the first place; it should be one of the targets that gets generated along with the object file.

As I read once more § [4.14 Generating Prerequisites Automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites) of the manual, the answer jumped out at me:

> The purpose of the sed command is to translate (for example):
>
> ```
> main.o : main.c defs.h
> ```
>
> into:
>
> ```
> main.o main.d : main.c defs.h
> ```

While my build system makes no use of `sed`, the fact that `main.d` was on the left-hand side of the example rule felt strange. In my code, it was on the right-hand side.

When I put my rule in the left-hand side, it worked and the problem was solved. The erroneous recipe was essentially treating one of its byproducts as a prerequisite.

Comment: `.d` are not used by the linker (or compiler).  They are compiler-generated makefiles, to be included by the parent makefile, 
defining the dependencies of `foo.o` upon headers that would otherwise not be known as prerequisites. They prompt *make* to re-*compile* `foo.o` when it is out of date with respect to any header included by `foo.c|cpp`.

Comment: See
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation)
[this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)
and [this](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/automatically_generate_makefile_dependencies.html)

Comment: @MikeKinghan, I don't think I understand this process as well as I would like. I was under the impression that both object files and libraries had to be linked in a specific order, according to the dependencies between them. I think this is the problem [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) aims to solve. Is this not correct? If not, can you please clarify; I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Object files and libraries need to be linked in such an order, that any of them which *requires* a symbol definition occurs before the one that *provides* the symbol definition - *in the linker commandline*. These
require/provide relations are linkage dependencies but are not at all the same as `make` dependencies, which are relations of the form: if X is newer than Y, then do Z. `.d` files express `make` dependencies: the linker knows nothing of them.  The order in which things are linked is entirely independent of the order in which they are made by `make`.