# When I compile in C I have an error of imports in header files

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, compiler-errors

I got the next error when I compile my project.

```
./PC.h:15:12: error: unknown type name 'InstructionMemory'
PC *new_pc(InstructionMemory *memoria);
           ^
./PC.h:17:1: error: unknown type name 'InstructionMemory'
InstructionMemory *get_memory(PC *programCounter);
^
2 errors generated.
In file included from main.c:5:
./InstructionRegister.h:7:36: error: unknown type name 'BankRegister'
int opera(InstructionRegister *IR, BankRegister *bank);
```

But this don't makes me sense, I look at the files and they are headers files, so I know that you can not use #include into headers file. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

There is the content of my PC.h file:

```
typedef struct PC PC;
PC *new_pc(InstructionMemory *memoria);
int getpc(PC *programCounter);
InstructionMemory *get_memory(PC *programCounter);
char *fecth(PC *programCounter);
char *linea_actual(PC *programCounter);
```

I use the next makefile to compile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS=-I
DEPS = ALU.h InstructionRegister.h Rebasing.h BankRegister.h MemoryInstruction.h ControlUnit.h PC.h

run: exect
    ./exect $(EX)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)

exect: ALU.c InstructionRegister.c Rebasing.c BankRegister.c MemoryInstruction.c main.c ControlUnit.c PC.c
    gcc -o exect InstructionRegister.c Rebasing.c BankRegister.c MemoryInstruction.c main.c ControlUnit.c PC.c -I.


clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: `PC.h` needs to include whatever defines `InstructionMemory`. Or use a forward declaration

Comment: You needn't compile header files.

Comment: "*I know that you can not use #include into headers file*" - yes, you can.

Comment: " I know that you can not use #include into headers file". Says who?

Comment: Thanks to all to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I know that you cannot use `#include` into headers file.

You are mistaken. You can, and often should and want to, use several [include directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) in your header file.

A typical small C project (e.g. less than a hundred thousands lines of C code in total) often would have a *single* common header file, e.g. `myheader.h`, typically starting with an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and several system includes, so like

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_INCLUDED
#define MYHEADER_INCLUDED

// some system includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/// your type declarations
enum foo_en { /* blablabla */ };
struct bar_st { /* blablabla */ };
typedef struct bar_st Bar;
/* etc... */

/// your global functions 
extern int myglobfun(int, int);
/* etc...*/

/// your global variables (have only a few of them)
extern Bar*my_bar;
/* etc... */

#endif /*MYHEADER_INCLUDED*/
```

This is just one possibility of organizing a project. Some people prefer to have many header files and explicitly `#include`  system headers before some of their own headers in every of their translation units (e.g. C source files).

The advantage of having a single common header is that the `Makefile` is simple to code, and you might even [precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) your common header. A disadvantage is that any change (e.g. adding a field in a common `struct`) in that header forces `make` to recompile everything (not a big deal for a small project).

Alternatively you could have many header files, then be sure to use  [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (in the single common header case it is actually useless but does not harm) in them, and to define a discipline regarding multiple inclusion. Often, a header file would itself include other needed header files, or else check that they have been included, e.g. with

```
 // file "myheaderone.h"
 #ifndef MYHEADERONE_INCLUDED

 // check that "myotherheader.h" has been included
 #ifndef MYOTHERHEADER_INCLUDED
 #error myotherheader.h should have been #include-d
 #endif

 //// etc
```

Alternatively you might code `#include "myotherheader.h"` near the beginning of `myfirstheader.h`

If you have multiple headers, you need a complex `Makefile` and you'll rather generate the dependencies, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025816/841108). It uses some [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to `gcc` like `-M` and friends.

BTW, your `Makefile` is wrong. Don't hardcode `cc` in it (but use `$(CC)`). Be [sure](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) to ask [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for all warnings & debug info (e.g. `CFLAGS= -Wall -g`). Learn about GNU make [catalog of rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) by running [`make -p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html). And your `CFLAGS= -I` is really wrong, you might want `CFLAGS= -I. -Wall -g` since `-I` should *always* be followed by a directory.

PS. If using `gcc` take the habit of *always* passing `-Wall` to it. Very often (and certainly in your case) you also want `-Wextra` (to get even more warnings; remember the compiler warnings are your friends and you should improve your code till you have none of them) and probably `-g` (to be able to use the `-g` debugger). For benchmarking purposes ask the compiler to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. with `-O1` or `-O2 -mcpu=native`).

Be aware of the [`-H` preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html): it is asking `gcc` to show every included file. Sometimes (e.g. to debug some nasty macro) you want to see the preprocessed form of a translation unit, use `gcc -C -E` to get it.

Comment: Ok, I will take consideration of this, now this compile. Thanks.