# Can I create dependencies file on the go and decide whether to rebuild?

Tags: makefile

I want my makefile to be able to automatically create dependencies file and then decide whether a rebuild is needed.
While searching for a way to do it I found the following solution: I'm adding this line to my makefile:

```
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

and to the recipe for building .o files

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) $<
```

I added the line

```
    $(CC) $(STD) -MM $< -o $*.d
```

If I understand correctly, every time an .o file doesn't exist, it ignores the include and build the .o file. Later, if I run make again, it checks the dependencies for this .o file (which he gets from the .d file) and decides whether it should rebuild the .o file.
For that, once I build my project, I have to keep all these .d files.

What I want, is that every time make encounter the decision whether to rebuild or not an .o file, it will generate a .d file, specifically for this .o file. According to this .d file it will decide whether to rebuild, and delete the .d file when finished.

Is there a way I can achieve that?

I hope I expressed my will clear enough. If not, here's the flow I imagine:

```
if (.o file doesn't exist): build it
otherwise: build a .d file  
           rebuild or do nothing (according to the .d file)  
           delete the .d file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile (Auto-Dependency Generation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation). Get rid of the extra line and use `-MMD -MP` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is how make already works, except for the deleting of the `.d` file.  I don't know why you want that: it means that every time make runs it will have to rebuild the `.d` file before it can tell if an object file is out of date: this will increase your build times dramatically for no good reason.

Every time make rebuilds any included makefile, it will re-exec itself and start reading makefiles from scratch.  So as long as you don't delete the `.d` file it will work as you desire.  Information about this feature is in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).

However, this is a sub-optimal way of managing dependencies.  It works but it is slower than it needs to be.  An explanation of a more "modern" way to handle this can be found [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).