# C++ Makefile, is it possible to factorize it even more?

Tags: c++, makefile, project-structure

I have a project for school and I want to write a Makefile, I have seen some examples of using Makefile with multiple source directories and multiple executables but still could not implement it properly to my Makefile.

**PS: I'm using doctest for the unit testing (and I can't change it).**

Here is the project structure (and I can't change it):

```
.
├── bin
├── build
├── extern
│   └── doctest.h
├── include
│   ├── file1.hpp
│   └── file2.hpp
├── src
│   ├── file1.cpp
│   └── file2.cpp
├── tests
│   ├── file1-test.cpp
│   └── file2-test.cpp
└──  Makefile
```

I have the following directories:

- `bin`: for all the executables.
- `build`: for all the objects (`.o`).
- `extern`: for the doctest header (this is where I would have stored any other library)
- `include`: for all the headers (`.hpp`).
- `src`: for all the classes (`.cpp`).
- `tests`: for all the unit tests (also `.cpp`)

You can see `file1.cpp` as a class, `file1.hpp` as the class header and `file1-test.cpp` as the unit tests for the class.

Here is my Makefile:

```
BIN_DIR := bin/
BUILD_DIR := build/
EXTERN_DIR := extern/
INCLUDE_DIR := include/
SOURCE_DIR := src/
TESTS_DIR := tests/
DEP_DIR := .dep/

DEPENDS := $(patsubst %.o, $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR)%.d, $(notdir $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)*.o)))

EXE := $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR), file1-test file2-test)

OBJS_1 := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o)
OBJS_2 := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o file2.o)

CXX := clang++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -std=c++11 -g -O3 -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(EXTERN_DIR)

vpath %.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR) $(TESTS_DIR)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

$(BUILD_DIR) $(BIN_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR)$(notdir $(basename $@).d) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR)%: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(BIN_DIR)file1-test: $(OBJS_1)
$(BIN_DIR)file2-test: $(OBJS_2)

.PRECIOUS: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o

-include $(DEPENDS)

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BIN_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR)
```

**So my questions are:**

- Is my Makefile following good practices ?
- Is it optimized ? If no, how can I make it even better ?
- For every new executable I've to add a `OBJS_X` variable and a target `$(BIN_DIR)fileX-test: $(OBJS_X)`, can i get rid of it ? If yes can someone write me some generic rule, so I don't have to specify a variable and a target every time I want a new executable.
- If I want to compile only one executable I have to use `make bin/fileX-test`. Is it possible to run only `make fileX-test` instead of `make bin/fileX-test` (but still building it in the `bin` directory) ? I tried to implement a rule like this: `fileX-test: $(BIN_DIR)fileX-test` but it's not working as I want, at the very end of the compilation it starts executing builtin rules and I don't know why. Can someone explain ?

**Final answer:**

This is what I considere a good answer, if it can help someone later:

```
BIN_DIR := bin/
BUILD_DIR := build/
EXTERN_DIR := extern/
INCLUDE_DIR := include/
SOURCE_DIR := src/
TESTS_DIR := tests/
DEP_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR).dep/

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -std=c++11 -g -O3 -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(EXTERN_DIR)
DEPFLAGS := -MMD -MP -MF $(DEP_DIR)

vpath %.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR) $(TESTS_DIR)

file1-test_OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o)
file2-test_OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o file2.o)

EXE := $(patsubst %_OBJECTS, %, $(filter %_OBJECTS, $(.VARIABLES)))

.PHONY: all keep help check clean $(EXE)

all: $(EXE:%=$(BIN_DIR)%)

$(foreach E, $(EXE), $(eval $(BIN_DIR)$E: $($E_OBJECTS)))
$(foreach E, $(EXE), $(eval $E: $(BIN_DIR)$E ;))

$(BUILD_DIR) $(BIN_DIR) $(DEP_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR) $(DEP_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS)$(@F:.o=.d) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR)%: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^

-include $(wildcard $(DEP_DIR)*.d)

keep: $(EXE:%=$(BUILD_DIR)%.o)

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)* $(BUILD_DIR)* $(DEP_DIR)*
```

Comment: Ad.3. yes, you have to add a list of objects required by target otherwise you get undefined references or multiple definitions (of main usually)

Comment: @tansy Yes that's what I was suspecting but we managed to make it "decent" (I think), see edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly your makefile is pretty good.  There are some simplifications you can make, but they're just syntax and not really performance etc.:

```
DEP_DIR := .dep/
```

You never use this by itself so if you change its definition to:

```
DEP_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR).dep/
```

you can simplify the references to it.

```
DEPENDS := $(patsubst %.o, $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR)%.d, $(notdir $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)*.o)))

-include $(DEPENDS)
```

this seems complex.  Why not get rid of DEPENDS and just write:

```
include $(wildcard $(DEP_DIR)*.d)
```

This:

```
@$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEP_DIR)$(notdir $(basename $@).d) -c $< -o $@
```

is also complex.  You can write it (if you simply `DEP_DIR`) as:

```
@$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $(DEP_DIR)$(@F:.o=.d) -c $< -o $@
```

For:

```
.PRECIOUS: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o
```

I would definitely NOT use this.  `.PRECIOUS` should be rarely, if ever, used.  If you're trying to avoid object files being considered intermediate it's best to just list them directly as prerequisites, such as:

```
keep : $(EXE:$(BIN_DIR)%=$(BUILD_DIR)%.o)
```

But unless you have special need to look at these object files it doesn't hurt to let make delete them.

Regarding your question about shortcuts: the reason you see the behavior you do is that your target definition:

```
fileX-test: $(BIN_DIR)fileX-test
```

has no recipe attached to it, so make will try to find a recipe using an implicit rule.  It finds built-in recipe for `% : %.c`, and because you set `vpath` it can find a `%.c` file that matches, so it uses it.  To avoid this you can just give an empty recipe; replace the above with:

```
fileX-test: $(BIN_DIR)fileX-test ;
```

(note added semicolon).

Your main question is how to simplify this:

```
EXE := $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR), file1-test file2-test)

OBJS_1 := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o)
OBJS_2 := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), file1.o file2.o)

all: $(EXE)

$(BIN_DIR)file1-test: $(OBJS_1)
$(BIN_DIR)file2-test: $(OBJS_2)
```

You can do this automatically but doing so requires knowing the deeper parts of GNU make.  You might find this set of blog posts interesting: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/ (start with the bottom / oldest and work your way up).

Replace the above with:

```
# Write one of these for each program you need:

file1-test_OBJECTS = file1.o
file2-test_OBJECTS = file1.o file2.o

# Now everything below here is boilerplate

EXE = $(patsubst %_OBJECTS,%,$(filter %_OBJECTS,$(.VARIABLES)))

all: $(EXE:%=$(BIN_DIR)%)

$(foreach E,$(EXE),$(eval $(BIN_DIR)$E: $($E_OBJECTS)))
$(foreach E,$(EXE),$(eval $E: $(BIN_DIR)$E ;))
.PHONY: $(EXE)
```

Comment: Thanks you for this complete answer. I managed to make all the changes and it works fine now, but I still have some trouble with the part about `.PRECIOUS`, I have the keep rule (also declare it in .PHONY) but I don't know where should I call it ? I tried to call it here: `$(BIN_DIR)%: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o keep | $(BIN_DIR)` but it ends up with a `make: Circular dependency dropped`. Looking at: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html, using `.PRECIOUS` or `.SECONDARY` looks ok and even encouraged ?

Comment: You don't have to build the `keep` target anywhere.  It's just there so that the prerequisites are listed explicitly somewhere in the makefile.  `.PRECIOUS` means that if make is interrupted (say, you use ^C to stop it) while a rule is running that builds one of the `.PRECIOUS` targets, make won't clean up that partly-built target.  So you could have a corrupted object file lying around which is hard to debug, sometimes.  It is only appropriate for very specific, unusual situations.

Comment: I should say that well-behaved tools will _themselves_ delete the object file if they get interrupted, so for those kinds of tools it's not important that make does it.  Or, you can write your rules defensively so that they generate the output to a temporary file then use `mv` to rename them atomically.  But in general it's not a good idea to declare targets to be `.PRECIOUS` unless you really want that behavior.

Comment: I finally managed to get everything working fine, I edited my orginal post with the final answer. Thanks for the help and the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am turning my comment into an answer to allow others to disapprove this view: I think CMake is better here for you. Look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789644/difference-between-using-makefile-and-cmake-to-compile-the-code) for some differences between Make and CMake and arguments for CMake.

Advantages related to your questions:

- It will allow you more easily to follow good practices
- It scales much better
- You do not have to write so muc boilerplate for new executable added to your code
- Building a single executable is possible, see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412591/cmake-project-build-only-one-specific-executable-and-its-dependencies) as a hint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's probably what I would have used if I had no subject restrictions (I should have said it in my original post).