# Is it correct to compile source file with object files together?

Tags: c, build, compilation

Imagine I have `file1.c`, `file2.c`. First I compile one file with `gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o`. Is it OK to compile them together with `gcc file1.o file2.c -o prog`? I tried it and no errors are shown, but should I compile `file2.o` first? Is it correct to mix `.c` and `.o` files?

Comment: What you're doing is viable for the toolchain you're using (likely clang, gcc, mingw, whatever). you'll ultimately find it is easier to xform your build instructions into actual build systems (make, cmake, etc.) if you stick to the principle of source -> target, however.

Comment: @WhozCraig I use GNU make and I found out it mixes .c and .o (because I wrote it a bit wrong) with GCC compiler

Comment: GnuMake isn't doing that; *you* are. Make will (try to) do whatever you tell it to do. Anyway, since you're already in Make land, you may as well upsize to doing things like [automatic dependencies generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation) at which point it will become pretty clear pretty quickly how moving toward target per source is a good pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do `gcc file1.o file2.c -o prog`. You can also do  `gcc file1.c file2.c -o prog`.

GCC will handle compiling file2.c behind the scenes.