# Recursive Dependencies Between make Targets in Same Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am attempting to write a makefile that is able to determine when headers were changed and then recompile the corresponding .cpp files. To test this, I created three files: `main.cpp`, `a.h`, and `b.h`. `main.cpp` include s`a.h` and `a.h` includes `b.h`.

My makefile looks like this:

```
prog: main.cpp a.h
        g++ main.cpp -o prog

a.h: b.h
```

When any combination of `a.h`, `b.h`, and `main.cpp` is changed, I expect `prog` to be recompiled. Despite this, `prog` is only recompiled when `a.h` or `main.cpp` is changed, with the last line seeming to be ignored.

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I accomplish what I want without adding the full and complete set of headers to each individual .cpp file like this (since for larger projects this could become *extremely* cumbersome):

```
prog: main.cpp a.h b.h
        g++ ...
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding this line `a.h:b.h`. Are you trying to say that `a.h` depends on `b.h` ? If so does a.h `#inlcude b.h`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394609/makefile-header-dependencies  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857837/compile-headers-dependencies-with-makefile  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297514/how-can-i-have-a-makefile-automatically-rebuild-source-files-that-include-a-modi

Comment: @Rishi You are correct in that a.h includes b.h.

Comment: @celtschk From those questions I seemed to gather that makepp does what I want (it works with my makefile as intended). Perhaps that would make a good answer here? I am not good enough in make to determine if the more complicated syntax in your linked questions is equivalent to mine.

Comment: by placing the header file name as one of the dependencies in the `prog: ...` recipe, the `make` utility will look at the time stamp of the file and re-run the compile and link step.  So the makefile needs nothing special to cause that to happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing incorrectly

Your rule:

```
a.h: b.h
```

merely tells `make` that `a.h` depends on `b.h`, i.e. that `a.h` will need to
be (re)made, in whatever manner `make` can determine from the makefile, if
`a.h` is older than `b.h` or doesn't exist.

It doesn't tell `make` *what to do* to remake `a.h` from `b.h`. Your makefile
contains no *recipe* for remaking `a.h` from `b.h`. It only contains a recipe
for remaking `prog` from `main.cpp` and `a.h`, namely:

```
prog: main.cpp a.h
        g++ main.cpp -o prog
```

Furthermore `make`, of course, has no builtin rule with a recipe for making
`a.h` from `b.h`. So in the absence of *any* recipe for making `a.h` from `b.h`
it assumes that this dependency requires *nothing to be done*. There is no
other reasonable default. So even if `a.h` is older than `b.h`, nothing
is done to `a.h`; and although `prog` depends on `a.h`, nothing need be done
to `prog` on that account.

This is fortunate, because in fact you *don't want* `a.h` to be remade in
any manner whatever when `b.h` changes, and you don't want `main.cpp` to be
remade in any manner whatever when `a.h` or `b.h` changes. You want *prog* to be
remade when any of them changes. What you want is expressed by any of the
following makefiles:

**1**

```
prog: main.cpp a.h b.h
    g++ main.cpp -o prog
```

**2**

```
prog: main.cpp a.h
    g++ main.cpp -o prog

prog: b.h
```

**3**

```
prog: main.cpp b.h
    g++ main.cpp -o prog

prog: a.h
```

**4**

```
prog: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -o prog

prog: a.h b.h
```

**5**

```
prog: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -o prog

prog: a.h
prog: b.h
```

(and some more). They're all equivalent. They all say that `prog` depends
on `main.cpp`, `a.h` and `b.h` and they all say what is to be done whenever
`prog` needs to remade, namely:

```
    g++ main.cpp -o prog
```

> how can I accomplish what I want without adding the full and complete set of
>   headers to each individual .cpp file like this 
>   (since for larger projects this could become extremely cumbersome)

Indeed it would, and for that reason GCC compilers have for a very long time had
a feature for generating mini-makefiles that express the dependency of
the object file that is going to be generated upon each of the header files that
are read in order to make the object file. GNU make can exploit this feature
to generate those *dependency files* and include them in a makefile for building GCC target(s). This co-operation between
GCC and `make` is called *auto-dependency generation* (or similar). The
question of how to do it in a makefile is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394609/1362568)
and if you google, e.g. "gcc auto generate dependencies" you can also find guru treatments.

In a comment you suggest that you aren't yet sufficiently expert with GNU
make to be confident with the auto-dependency generation techniques illustrated
in [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394609/1362568). Well, you
can *begin* to get the hang of it with a rudimentary implementation as simple
as this (which also makes the makefile more normal in other respects):

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: prog.o

prog.o: main.cpp
    g++ -MMD -c -o prog.o main.cpp

prog: prog.o
    g++ -o prog prog.o 

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o *.d

-include prog.d
```

`-MMD` is the GCC preprocessor option that generates the dependency file
`prog.d`. Here is [the documentation of `-MMD`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html)

`prog.d` is a mini-makefile:

```
$ cat prog.d 
prog.o: main.cpp a.h b.h
```

expressing all of the dependencies of `prog.o`. The first time this runs,
the `include`-ed makefile `prog.d` will not exist, which would be a fatal `make`
error but for the fact that the `-` prefix tells `make` to ignore that error.
So `make` proceeds and everything, including `prog.d` gets made, and thereafter
`prog.d` will be regenerated whenever any rule - including the rule in `prog.d`
itself - requires `prog.o` to be recompiled.