# MAKEFILE: treating target as updated without modifying the file

Tags: c++, c, makefile

How can I make GNU make to treat a target as modified without modifying target file (no recipe body)?

I have header file which includes another header file.

program.h:

```
//include guard    

#include "dependencies.h"

//some actual signatures
```

and makefile:

```
program: program.o dependencies.o
  g++ -o program program.o dependencies.o

program.o: program.cpp program.h
  g++ -c program.cpp

dependencies.o: dependencies.cpp dependencies.h
  g++ -c dependencies.cpp

program.h: dependencies.h
  # I would like that this target was treated as modified after
  # dependencies.h changes
```

In the above example when dependencies.h changes only dependencies.o is recompiled leaving program.o untouched and thus the build will probably fail. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Thanks.

Alek

Comment: Your question in general is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394609/makefile-header-dependencies . Here is another example: http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
program.o: program.cpp program.h
  g++ -c program.cpp

dependencies.o: dependencies.cpp dependencies.h
  g++ -c dependencies.cpp
```

To be:

```
OBJ_FILES = program.o dependencies.o
DEP_FILES = $(patsbust %.o,%.d,$(OBJ_FILES))

%.o : %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d) -o $@

program : $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^

-include $(DEP_FILES)
```

This will have `g++` autogenerate your dependency files for you (into the `.d`) files. Those files will have makefile-style rules for dependencies. In this case, I'd expect:

```
program.o : dependencies.h
```

The `-include` will add those to your makefile. That way, you don't have to hardcode your dependencies - let the compiler figure it out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Make your program depend on its dependencies in full:

```
program.o: program.cpp program.h dependencies.h
  g++ -c program.cpp
```

This is of course given that your `program.o` actually depends on `dependencies.h`. If `dependencies.h` is an internal implementation detail of `program.h`, then your code should compile and link just fine without recompiling `program.o`.

Comment: I'm doing it exactly like you say but this is tedious if there are more chained dependencies (and they are not an implementation detail but are part of a signatures f.e.). I'm left with lines like this:
`main.o: myWindows.h myViewModels.h iMyView.h model.h $(DALINCLUDEDIR)/$(DALHEADER) $(GUIINCLUDEDIR)/$(GUIHEADER) $(SERVERINCLUDEDIR)/$(SERVERHEADER)`

Comment: Then maybe Barry's automated solution will help :)