# Including Header(.hpp) files in C++ MAKEFILES

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

My problem is, that my makefile DOES NOT work if i use a Variable (HEADER) where i put in all the .hpp files and call that using $(HEADER) inside the main.exe: main.o $(HEADER) ... rule.

It does work though if i use: main.exe: main.o 1.hpp 2.hpp 3.hpp ..... which does not make any sense for me at all.

So my understanding of makefiles is, of course, to combine big amounts of .hpp / .cpp -> .o files to create an executable file.

I was doing an exercise, where i have to create a bunch of classes, subclasses etc. and do some stuff with it inside the main.cpp.

So while doing the exercise i peaked into the solutions and i saw that my professor has not even used .cpp files for the class function definitions, but has done it all inside the .hpp files, because it's only a few lines of code per class. I accepted that, because it would create unnecessary (.cpp) files.

I've finished everything and then began writing my Makefile, as i launched it i got errors.
This is my Makefile:

```
COMPILER=g++ -c
COMPILER_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3
LINKER=g++

HEADER = function.hpp integral.hpp polynom.hpp trigonom.hpp riemann.hpp montecarlo.hpp

all: main.exe

main.exe: main.o $(HEADER)
    $(LINKER) $^ -o$@

%.o: %.cpp 
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o$@

clean:
    rm -f *.o 

.PHONY: all clean
```

It did not work, so i thought okay, maybe the .hpp files are not converted to .o files, so i added

```
%.o: %.hpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o$@
```

which actually made it work. I have realised though that technically this could lead to problems because i already have the %.o : %.cpp inside my file...

At this point I just got more and more confused, and when i looked into the solution makefile, which looks like this:

```
COMPILER=g++ -c
COMPILER_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3
LINKER=g++

all: main.exe

main.exe : main.o function.hpp integral.hpp polynom.hpp trigonom.hpp riemann.hpp montecarlo.hpp
    $(LINKER) $< -o$@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o$@
    
clean: 
    rm -f *.o 

.PHONY: all clean
```

I just didn't really understand anything anymore. Why does it work if you put the .hpp files behind the main.o inside the main.exe Rule, but it DOES NOT work if i put a Variable $(HEADER) behind the main.o file, inside that Rule. Where is the difference??? Why does it work the one way and why does it not the other?
Also what is the purpose of doing a Makefile in the scenario where you only use header (.hpp) files at all? Technically i could also just compile main.cpp because i have all the .hpp files included inside my main.cpp at the top using e.g. #include "montecarlo.hpp".

I understand that if i call the rule main.exe it takes all the object files and binds them together to create the .exe file. I tried some other variations where i put main.o inside the HEADER variable as well, or changed all .hpp endings to .o inside the HEADER variable as well. Didn't work.

Hope anyone can help, sorry for the long text. Thank you!

Comment: "did not work" is a useless diagnostic. What was the error message?

Comment: Makefiles require that the recipes are indented by a TAB character. Not four spaces. It is hard to tell from your post whether that is the case, but this is a common gotcha.

Comment: Why do you even try to "compile" headers in the first place? Something is fishy here. Headers should never show up in makefiles normally... You'd `#include` them from within your *.cpp files, that's their point!

Comment: Why does `main.exe` depend on `$(HEADERS)`?  And why does the link command use `$^` which will cause it to link those headers.  You need to consider your dependencies more carefully.  Also note the difference between `$^` and `$<`.

Comment: I don't think it's an duplicate, but you can find a solution here [Makefile, header dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394609/makefile-header-dependencies). I usually see something like this in companies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24244065/16540390

Comment: This has nothing to do with a variable, whatsoever. Either way the dependency of the executable on the headers means that the executable only gets relinked, and nothing gets recompiled if the header files are out of date relative to the executable. The only dependencies are between the executable and the header files. To update the dependency: run the linker. This is called The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "Your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do".

Comment: As for your other question: using a Makefile standardizes the build command and configuration options. By using only a single .cpp file your professor is missing out on two other important benefits of makefiles: only rebuilding things that (depend on things that) changed, trivial parallel compilation of your project.

Comment: ChatGPT can be useful if you're capable of determining whether it is correct or not. You can't rely on it as a source of dependable facts - it has no actual knowledge about anything.

Comment: @molbdnilo :  It is also irrelevant information unless the ChatGPT attempt/advice were posted - so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as `make` is concerned, there is no difference between these two snippets:

```
main.exe : main.o function.hpp integral.hpp polynom.hpp trigonom.hpp riemann.hpp montecarlo.hpp
    $(LINKER) $^ -o$@
```

and

```
HEADER = function.hpp integral.hpp polynom.hpp trigonom.hpp riemann.hpp montecarlo.hpp
main.exe: main.o $(HEADER)
    $(LINKER) $^ -o$@
```

The purpose of putting the headers in the rule dependencies makes `make` rerun the rule if its inputs change.

However, your professor made a big mistake: since main.cpp `#include`s all the header files and it is the **only** translation unit, you *must* recompile main.cpp every time the headers change. The stated rule only re-links but does not recompile main.cpp...

The proper solution is to make main.o depend on the header files, and then you can simplify the rule for main.exe significantly:

```
main.o: $(HEADER)

main.exe: main.o
    $(LINKER) $< -o $@
```

The `%.o: %.cpp` rule in your makefile will provide the recipe, but you can always add extra dependencies as I have shown.

Finally, Make comes with a built-in rule for compiling .cpp files that uses the `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` variables, so if you just define the expected variables you can get away with even less.

The final version of your Makefile can thus be as simple as this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3
HEADER = function.hpp integral.hpp polynom.hpp trigonom.hpp riemann.hpp montecarlo.hpp

all: main.exe

main.exe: main.o
    $(CXX) $< -o $@

main.o: $(HEADER)

clean:
    -rm -f *.o main.exe

.PHONY: all clean
```