# Easy makefiles for gcc/g++

Tags: linux, dependencies, makefile

My projects almst always consist of:

1. Pairs of Foo.h and Foo.cpp
2. Some extra headers util.h etc.

What is the simplest way to write a makefile that

- Runs

  ```
  $CC -c foo.cpp
  ```

for each .cpp file, keeping a dependency to its coresponding .h file

- Provides some way that I can manually add extra dependencies
- Includes a linking step with my manuall set $LIBS variable.

I work with Linux(Ubuntu) and gcc/g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

# Some things have extra dependencies. (Headers like util.h are unlikely
# to change, but you can handle them this way if you really want to.)
#
# foo.o and bar.o both depend on baz.h
foo.o bar.o: baz.h

# foo.o also depends on gab.h and jig.h
foo.o: gab.h jig.h

# You will need a list of object files. You can build it by hand:
OBJ_FILES = foo.o bar.o snaz.o # and so on

# ...or just grab all the files in the source directory:
SOURCE_FILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES = $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o)

# It is possible to get this from the environment, but not advisable.
LIBS = -lred -lblue

final-thing: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: @Jack Kelly: Yes, I am familiar with more advanced methods like mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html, but look at the question.

Answer (score 3):

Please, just use `automake`. You'll get proper dependency tracking, makefiles that comply with the [GNU Makefile Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html) (e.g., `make install` does the correct thing and respects `DESTDIR` and `prefix`), the ability to check for system quirks as needed and support for building proper distribution tarballs.

This is a minimal `configure.ac`:

```
                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.61])
AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

# Checks for library functions.

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and a minimal `Makefile.am`:

```
## Process this file with automake to generate Makefile.in
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.cpp bar.h baz.h quux.cpp
```

Run `autoreconf -i` to generate the configure script, followed by `./configure` and `make`.

Here is an [excellent autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can check out [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html)?

If you're unfamiliar with CMake, it's basically a Makefile generator (or XCode, or Visual Studio Projects, etc, depending on platform), so it lets you specify just the variables you need, and takes care of header dependency issues for you, makefile generation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple shell script that constructs a makefile from all .cpp files in a given directory:

```
# !sh    
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
echo -e "please give executable name"
exit 1
fi

echo -e -n "CC=g++\nOPTIMS=\nLIBS= " > makefile

echo >> makefile
echo -n "$1: " >> makefile
for fic in *.cpp
do
echo -n "${fic%\.cpp}.o " >> makefile
done

echo >> makefile
echo -n -e "\t\$(CC) " >> makefile
for fic in *.cpp
do
echo -n "${fic%\.cpp}.o " >> makefile
done
echo -n -e "-o $1 \$(OPTIMS) \$(LIBS)\n" >> makefile

echo >> makefile
for fic in *.cpp
do
g++ -MM $fic >> makefile
echo -e "\t\$(CC) -c $fic \$(OPTIMS)\n" >> makefile
done

exit 0
```

It uses the `-MM` option of gcc for creating makefile dependency lines. Just create the script in the sources directory, (let's call it `micmake`), make it executable (`chmod +x micmake`) and type

```
./micmake go
```

It will create a makefile and the `make` command compile your project. The executable is named `go`. You can edit the makefile if you need special compilation options or libraries. For more complex projects and dependencies, you should use automake, cmake or scons.

Answer (score 0):

start here [simple makefile for gcc](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_16.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from one of my projects -- you can simply drop new pairs `foo1.cc` and `foo1.h` in there and they will automagically be built for you:

```
# determine all sources and from that all targets
sources :=              $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs :=             $(sources:.cpp=)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules 
CXX :=                  g++
CPPFLAGS :=             -Wall 
CXXFLAGS :=             -O3 -pipe 
LDLIBS :=  

# build all and strip programs afterwards 
all:                    $(programs) 
                        @test -x /usr/bin/strip && strip $^
```

Comment: With no dependency on the header files there are cases where this will not rebuild after changes have been made. The usual `.depend` recipe will fix it. Multiple SO question address that issue including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297514/how-can-i-have-a-makefile-automatically-rebuild-source-files-that-include-a-modif.

Comment: Building `strip` into your compilation step seems like a really bad idea, especially for development. The GNU makefile conventions put stripping into its own target, `install-strip`: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Makefile-Conventions

Comment: As I said, it came from a local project -- where I considered strip to be appropriate.