# makefiles and header dependencies, revisited

Tags: c++, makefile

*This question is from an idealistic standpoint. // Forward declaration*

I've been learning the basics of makefiles and I found myself wondering the same thing that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297514/how-can-i-have-a-makefile-automatically-rebuild-source-files-that-include-a-modi) about header dependencies.  From a practical standpoint, I'm glad that there are solutions which solve the problem of header dependencies.  However, thinking on the question a bit more, I find myself asking why a header dependency would ever ***exclusively*** affect a compilation unit.  Under the assumption (see *forward declaration*) that definitions are contained in headers and implementation is defined in source units, is there any reason that modification to a header file is merited without modification to the respective source file?  If not, why does it even matter to recompile the dependent source unit(s) since a definition modification alone will have no affect on program execution?  Is it just a question of identifying errors in changes to interface definitions sooner rather than later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To be precise, *declarations* are contained in header files, and *definitions* (i.e. implementations) are in source files, but that's just terminology.)

> *"Is there any reason that modification to a header file is merited without modification to the respective source file?"*

Yes. Changing a member from `public` to `private`, for example. Also, more than one source file can #include a given header file, so a change to the header might require a change to one of them but not another. For example, adding/removing/renaming a data member in a class might not require any change in the the classes implementation, but still require a change in other source code that uses the class.

Even when a source file hasn't changed at all, it can still be logically necessary to recompile it if a header file has changed. For instance, adding/removing a data member changes the size of a class, which means that any code that uses instances of that class must adjust the amount of memory to allocate for them.

Comment: I didn't think about the case of class size.  It seems possible that if header dependencies weren't taken into account when a class definition change affects the class size, this could greatly affect the resulting executable if not all dependent CU's are recompiled.  Thanks!