# makefile add list of header files .h with no .c

Tags: c, makefile, include

I am writing the makefile of my own code and I realised that when I make the list of my source files I don't include some of them. In fact, what I do is the following:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)*.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCS_DIR)%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)%.o)
```

and them:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
@echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compiled $(TARGET) successfully! ***\n" ;
$(FL) $(LFLAGS) -o $(BUILDS_DIR)$@ \
    $(OBJS) \
    $(LIBS)
@echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Linking $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"

$(OBJS): $(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
    -c $<\
    -o $@
```

However, some of these files have not the .c but only the header one, ie:
    ...**common_functions.h**
    **common_macros.h**
    common_variables.c
    common_variables.h
    configure.c
    configure.h
    connectivity.c
    connectivity.h
    **enumerations.h**
    error_warning_table.c
    error_warning_table.h
    estimation.c
    estimation.h
    inout.c
    inout.h
    ...**structures.h**

So, of course, when I change something inside of them, they are not compiled again as they are not present in the SRCS list. How can I add them into the SRCS variable? or, how can I create a COMMONS variable with only these files and then compile them?

thanks a lot in advance,

Stefano

Comment: You can add the header files as dependencies of the object files.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/297514/10077

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I'll read it and try to see if i can fix with it.

Comment: ok it might be what I need but I don't get how I can do it in my case...

Comment: ok, I've done it. Actually I was just missing the -MD flag on my makefile because at the end I was already using
        depend: $(SRCS)
 makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
sorry. It was more silly than what I thought.