# How do you indicate relative (or absolute) path for pattern rule in makefile? and How do you detect included headers from a source file?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

We can add pattern rules such as `%.c` or `%.o` which mimics `*.c` or `*.o` in bash (it searches for all files that have extension `.c` or `.o`. This is very useful if you have several targets, so you don't have to write all rules. I would like to know how to use this trick if your target files (`.c` or `.o`) are in the previous directory. In bash, one can write `../*.c`, but `../%.c` does not work in makefile as I tested. How do you do such thing in makefile?

My second question:  sometimes one would like to add header dependencies like this:

```
HEADER=factorial.h

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
       gcc -o program $%
```

It is a good idea to add a header dependency because sometimes you don't know whether or not the included libraries have some change.

Here we have to manually type the file names for `HEADER`.

How do I make it so it can scan the target file's included headers? 
For example: my `main.c` has `#include "dog.h"`

How do I make it so it detects `main.c` has included `dog.h`.

Comment: For second question see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297514/how-can-i-have-a-makefile-automatically-rebuild-source-files-that-include-a-modi

Comment: `../%.o: ../%.c` is fine. Add an example that doesn't work as intended for you.

Comment: One question per Question, please.