# Proper makefile dependency list (C++)

Tags: c++, makefile

A lot of the examples I see regarding make files are somewhat inconsistent in regards to what files are considered dependencies of `main.o` and I was wondering what is the safest and most efficient way of going about creating a makefile.

An example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_quick_guide.htm:

```
hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
   $(CC) main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp functions.h
   $(CC) -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp functions.h
   $(CC) -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp functions.h
   $(CC) -c hello.cpp
```

As you can see, the header file `functions.h` is a dependency of `main.o`.

An example from my textbook:

```
myprog.exe : main.o threeintsfcts.o
    g++ main.o threeintsfcts.o -o myprog.exe

main.o : main.cpp threeintsfcts.cpp threeintsfcts.h
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp 

threeintsfcts.o : threeintsfcts.cpp threeintsfcts.h
    g++ -Wall -c threeintsfcts.cpp 

clean :
    rm *.o myprog.exe
```

As you can see, the header file `.h` and it's `.cpp` are dependencies of `main.o`.

I've also seen another example (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r7i5X0rXJk) where the only dependency of `main.o` is `main.cpp`.

Something like:

```
myprog.exe : main.o threeintsfcts.o
        g++ main.o threeintsfcts.o -o myprog.exe

    main.o : main.cpp 
        g++ -Wall -c main.cpp 

    threeintsfcts.o : threeintsfcts.cpp threeintsfcts.h
        g++ -Wall -c threeintsfcts.cpp 

    clean :
        rm *.o myprog.exe
```

---

When a `main.cpp` includes a `.h` file, should both the `.h` and its respective `.cpp` be included as dependencies?

One of the thoughts that came into my head was this: why should any `.h` file be included as a dependency anyways? Wouldn't a change in any `.h` file register as a change in the respective `.cpp` file since the contents of the `.h` are just going to be copy and pasted into the respective `.cpp` file through #include?

I am also unsure of whether to have the respective `.cpp` as a dependency.
(ex. `main.o : main.cpp threeintsfcts.cpp threeintsfcts.h`). 
I think doing so would go against one of the main benefits of makefiles which is the efficiency of modular compilation. (You would have to recompile the `main` whenever `threeintsfcts.cpp` changes).

However, it might make sense to do so in case `threeintsfcts.cpp` changes the name of one of its functions used in `main` and you forget to change it in `main`.

Comment: The whole point of the separate compilation model of C and C++ is that .cpp files are not dependent on other .cpp files.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from your textbook:

```
main.o : main.cpp threeintsfcts.cpp threeintsfcts.h
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp
```

is wrong. The purpose of separating source code into two files is so that they can be compiled independently; if one depends on the other, they have been separated incorrectly.

> "...Why should any .h file be included as a dependency anyways?
>   Wouldn't a change in any .h file register as a change in the
>   respective .cpp file since the contents of the .h are just going to be
>   copy and pasted into the respective .cpp file through #include?"

If `threeintsfcts.h` is the only file that has been changed, then `main.cpp` has not been changed. Make is not smart enough to parse `main.cpp` and deduce that `threeintsfcts.h` ought to be a prerequisite of `main.o`. (There are ways to get Make to do that, but you must master the basics first.)

> ...In case threeintsfcts.cpp changes the name of one of its functions
>   used in main and you forget to change it in main.

In that case you will not be able to build the executable; Make can (and will) inform you of the problem, but not fix it, no matter how you arrange the prerequisite lists.

Answer (score 2):

Each object file target needs to depend on its source file, obviously, but also all header files that it is including. The `make` program itself does not parse the source files, so it doesn't know what headers a source file includes. If one of the header files is missing and modified, the source file will not be automatically recompiled by `make`.

Because tracking the header file dependencies manually is cumbersome and error-prone, there are tools to automate it, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297514/how-can-i-have-a-makefile-automatically-rebuild-source-files-that-include-a-modif/2501673).

Other source files should however not be dependencies, because one source file should not be including another, so there cannot be any dependency that isn't resolved in the later linker step in the main executable target.

Any change in one source file that would affect a change in the compilation step of another source file would have to be through a change in the former source file's header file which is included in the later one. Therefore the header dependencies are sufficient.

Therefore I see no justification for the textbook example you posted. The first example is fine however, as long as the project size is small enough to track the dependencies manually. The third example is wrong, because it wont recompile `main.cpp` if the header file changes. (Assuming `threeintsfcts.h` is included in `main.cpp`, which is the only thing making sense)

Comment: So make doesn't parse source files, it just knows that it was modified?

Comment: @csguy Yes, it looks at the modification dates of files to figure out whether any of the dependencies have been edited after the target was created/modified. It doesn't care about the contents.

Comment: Make doesn't know anything about any particular programming languages.  It can be used with C, C++, latex, FORTRAN, or _anything_ else where if one file changes then some command needs to be run to bring another file up to date.  So no, it doesn't have any built-in ability to parse C code.

Answer (score 1):

No you shouldn't have .cpp dependency to main, the whole point of Makefile is for separate compilation.

If you were to include .cpp as a dependency to main, then every time the implementation of that cpp changes main and the cpp would get recompiled which is not what we want. Rather, we only want the cpp file to get re-compiled and main stay the same.

I think that the example from your textbook is a mistake.
I could be wrong, Makefiles is an old friend for me, so I want to know what others have to say on the matter.

I'm answering based on what I personally do and this is what also makes sense to me.

Comment: It would be great if you could extend your answer how to generate dependencies to header files using the compiler options for a `.d` make include.

Comment: For non-deliverable code (experiments, small tools, demonstrations, evaluations, research, etc., more than 75% of my code, these days), including multiple .cpp files into one compilation unit saves me time.  The compiler certainly does not care.  For deliverable code, and when I'm working on my make files, and when separate compilation is more important to my efforts, I take fewer, if any, short cuts.  I can not remember the last time I had circular includes, which are disguised by 'proper' include sequences, but easily avoided and handled with multiple .cpp files 'tumbled' together..